# Regular Expression for last folder in path

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I've been trying to capture the last folder in a folder path using regular expressions in C# but am just too new to this to figure this out.  For example if I have C:\Projects\Test then the expression should return Test.  If I have H:\Programs\Somefolder\Someotherfolder\Final then the result should be Final.  I've tried the below code but it just blows up.  Thanks for any help.

```
string pattern = ".*\\([^\\]+$)";
Match match = Regex.Match("H:\\Projects\\Final", pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you using a regex. You can just use [DirectoryInfo.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx)

```
var directoryname = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Projects\Test").Name;
\\The variable directoryname will be Test
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this?

```
string strRegex = @".*\\(.*)"; RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline; 
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions); 
string strTargetString = @"H:\Programs\Somefolder\Someotherfolder\Final"; 
string strReplace = @"$1";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Answer (score 2):

this is a bad use of regular expressions when you have a pretty complete set of .NET libraries that can do this for you... two easy methods using System.IO.Path or System.IO.DirectoryInfo below

```
        string path = @"H:\Programs\Somefolder\Someotherfolder\Final";
        Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path));
        Console.WriteLine(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path).Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use split?

string str = "c:\temp\temp1\temp2" ;

string lastfolder = str.Split("\").Last ;